# Copy the argv[1] into an array

Tags: c

I have the following code and I want instead of using the content of `buf[]` I want to have in `buf[]` only what is inside `argv[1]`.

Can I assign to an array the what is in `argv[1]`?

I want this code to separate my arguments that are stored in `argv[1]`.
Let s say I have :

```
/myprog "A 2 3 4" in.txt out.txt
```

`argv[1]` would be `"A 2 3,B 6 7,C 3,D 5"` and I want to separate everything in that location.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buf[]="a b c,d e f,g h i,e a b";
    int i = 0;
    int c=0;
    char *p = strtok (buf, ",");
    char *array[5];
    char *buf2[20];
    char *vec[20];
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        array[i++]=p;
        c++;
        p=strtok(NULL,",");
    }
    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
        printf("%s\n",array[i]);   
    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
        *(buf2+i)=*(array+i);
    int pos=0;
    int pa=c;
    c=0;
    for(pos=0;pos<pa;pos++)
    {
        char *q = strtok (buf2[pos], " ");
        i=0;
        while(q!=NULL)
        {
            vec[i++]=q;
            q=strtok(NULL," ");
            c++;
        }    
        for(i=0;i<c;i++)
            printf("%s\n", vec[i]);
        c=0;    
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that `buf` is large enough to fit the (null-terminated) string in `argv[1]` and just `strcpy` it?

Comment: Oh and you should add some bounds-checking for those `strtok` loops!

Comment: This `*(buf2+i)=*(array+i);` invokes undefined behaviour, as writing to where `buf2+i` points, with `buf2` not being initialised, so its elements point nowhere.

Comment: @alk No, since that's equal to `buf2[i] = array[i]` where both `buf2` and `array` are arrays of pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Oh well, yes, sure, you are right. I got lost in this somewhat strangely named variables.

Comment: @Robert: Good variable naming, and comments about what you're doing (and why), consistent style, and consistent use of variables (don't change purpose of a variable in the middle of the code) are all very important for your code to be readable and understandable and maintainable.

Comment: @alk Yeah it is a little messy.

Comment: "inside" `argv[1]` is a pointer. You can simply assign it to any compatible variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can tokenize `argv[1]` directly:

```
char *p = strtok (argv[1], ",");
```

(Provided, of course, that it exists: `argc > 1`).

Comment: The problem with this is that `strtok` *modifies* the string it tokenizes. This might not always be wanted and in the case of the command line arguments might not always be possible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you give an example when modifying `argv` may cause a problem?

Comment: It seems like I was wrong, [this `main` function reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) (which usually follow the standards closely) says it's okay. I apologize. ***But*** it still might not be wanted. :)